# Can you set the defaultSelected value of a select element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you set the defaultSelected value of a select field programmaticlly with javascript.  My problem is that when checking for values changed by the user I am getting true for the if condition below, when our developers programmaticlly change the selected option.  I want them to also update the defaultSelected.

```
        if (thisElement.options[j].selected !=
            thisElement.options[j].defaultSelected)
        {
          dirty = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever they make

```
select_element.value = 'someValue';
```

to select a value in drop down, make them also set the defaultSelected attribute of the option inside:

```
select_element.children[/*selected index*/].defaultSelected = true
```

**Edit.** In Jquery:

```
$('#select_element').val('someValue');
$('#select_element option:selected').attr('defaultSelected','true')
```

Comment: Would you have to iterate over existing options and set the .defaultSelected to false in unselected option? This would apply to both multiselect and regular select.